# Not Enough Disk Space for Boot Repair

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-repair, btrfs

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS and am now having problems booting my computer. It worked for a little bit but soon I was getting error messages that I was running out of space. I deleted an old version of MATLAB from `/usr/local` to make space and that's when the problem started. First, it said something to the effect of

```
[FAILED] Failed to start load/save random seed
See Systemctl status systemd-random-seed.service
```

So I tried to use a LiveUSB to reinstall. The installer did not recognize a distribution and instead wanted to erase everything. Now, I've tried boot repair but it says that there is not enough space on the disk to repair and boot (see [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/555dNzxPzS/)).

```
The sda2 (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) partition is nearly full. This can prevent to
start it. Please use the file browser that just opened to delete unused files 
(or transfer them to another disk). Close this window when you have finished.

The sda2 (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) partition is still full. This can prevent to
start it (e.g. you may get a Power Manager error).
```

It wanted me to move stuff from `/home` to free up space but my `/home` folder is on another hard drive. I then tried restarting my computer as usual (without the LiveUSB) and entered the root shell prompt. I used `sudo du -h --max-depth=1` to check my space and it said that was only using 40GB of space which should be more than enough free space as my root folder is located on a 120GB SSD with 32GB of swap meaning I have about 87GB of space for the OS.

Could anybody tell me what's up? Is it because I have a bunch of btrfs snapshots (at least some of the snapshots seem to have the old MATLAB version still)? If so, how would I go about removing them? And how would I prevent the creation of the snapshots going forward (or at least have them be replaced)?

Comment: apart from the issue you are having, I noticed you have 32GB of swap. You may not need this much swap. How much memory is installed on the system?

Comment: I currently have 32GB of RAM. It's a scientific computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you have a 32 GB swap partition. Try shrinking your swap partition down to 2 GB or so, and expanding the root partition to fill up the free space created on your drive.

By the way, in case you think that having a big huge swap partition will give you more RAM, swap doesn't work that way. It just acts as space on your drive to move inactive data in your RAM to.

Also, I believe deleting Btrfs snapshots is as simple as running `sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete`.

**I've never tried this command myself (because I've never used Btrfs, and hence never needed to try this command). So don't take my word for it.*

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just as an update, I followed your advice and it worked mostly. Unfortunately, ```/etc/fstab``` was overwritten and boot repair decided to put in a weird version of Grub. Luckily, I had a backup for ```fstab``` so everything seems to be working, if slightly off from previously.